# LWC import schema for Platform Event object?

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event

In LWCs, we can import an object reference like:

```
import MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/My_Custom_Object__c';
```

Can we do the same for platform events?

e.g.

```
import MY_PLATFORM_EVENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/My_Platform_Event__e';
```

The reason I ask is because I want to use it in my `subscribe` call. (A bit of an X-Y problem surrounding multiple 1GP packages, namespaces, etc.)

### Use Case

I have LWCs that use platform events that I'd like to use across multiple namespaced 1GP packages, and potentially subscriber org (without a namespace).

This is a bit of a follow up question to my previous question:  [Does a Managed Package LWC that subscribes to platform event need the namespace?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/390146/does-a-managed-package-lwc-that-subscribes-to-platform-event-need-the-namespace)

Comment: A question, why cant this be done by a simple custom label? like taking the objectAPIName directly from Custom label? And import custom label and subscribe to it?

`'/event/'+IMPORTED_CUSTOM_LABEL`

Comment: @NagendraSingh That falls into the namespace issue, presumably.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Because my problem is surrounding the namespace, which would therefore need to be added to the custom label

Comment: @NickCook Makes sense. I as thinking as the custom label can be imported without a namespace `{!$Label.c.<label_name>}`, thus giving you the flexibility to change this label as a post step. Definitely more complex than what you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - No.  There doesn't appear to be a way to import the platform event object.

There is some weird behaviour that I've included here for reference.

### Attempts to import the platform event object

You can import it and it will deploy successfully.

```
import MY_PLATFORM_EVENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/My_Platform_Event__e';
```

However, when you retrieve the LWC containing this code, the `__e` is replaced with `__c`.  If you then try to deploy that, the deployment will fail.

My first idea was to ignore this change, but when I released this as part of my managed package, the installation in subscriber org failed because it's trying to import `NAMESPACE__My_Platform_Event__c`, which doesn't exist.

### How did I get it to work?

In the end, I needed this code to work across multiple 1GP manage packages, so I had to make the namespace part dynamic.

I have a centralised Apex method that gets the namespace for me, which is what I used in my logic.

This approach works in the managed package development org, and in multiple subscriber orgs.

```
import getOurNamespace from '@salesforce/apex/Utils.getOurNamespace';

export default class MyLwc extends LightningElement {

    subscription;

    ourNamespace;
    @wire( getOurNamespace )
    wiredGetOurNamespace( result) {
        this.ourNamespace = result;

        this.subscribeToPlatformEvent();
    }
    
    subscribeToPlatformEvent() {
    
        if(this.ourNamespace.data && !this.subscription) {
    
            const platformEventObjectApiName = [this.ourNamespace.data, 'RecordChange__e'].join('__');
            
            subscribe(`/event/${platformEventObjectApiName }`, -1, (response) => { /* do things */ })
            then((response) => {
                this.subscription = response;
            })
        }
    }
    
}
```